# How to include a rendered php file that has been cached to HTML

Tags: php, html, caching, offline

I’m creating an Offline Web-App and working on the Caching method…
Since I use jquery, which is being updates all the time, and want to use cookies for these:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="themes/images/apple-touch-icon.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="themes/images/tstartup.png" />
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

So that they are only send to an IPhone… 
I need Server Side PHP to do that all for me… 
The Problem is that an PHP file if it’s cached it’s not calculated…
So that is my question, is there a way to let the server pre calculate the site then store it?

Ps sorry for my English

Comment: Store all of that in a file named `header-info.html` then use `<?php include 'header-info.html'; ?>` PHP files are not cached, they are usually run dynamically on html request. To cache a php page really kinda defeats the purpose, you could just use a .html instead.

Comment: you don't need to exclude these items from non-iphones its fine if they are in there for other browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still call a php code and variables even in cached files. There is a way how to "bypass" this. I don't know how exactly you cache, but using PHP it's something like this:

```
    <?php

    /*start caching*/
    ob_start();

    SOME PHP OR HTML CODE HERE

    /*this will store "already executed code" in cache and clears the buffer*/
    $storecodeincache .= ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    /*now at this point there is a piece of code we want to execute later, so we
use the same variable, but we store store PHP code we want execute later like this:*/      

    $storecodeincache .= 'SOMEPHPCODE';

    /*we start regular caching again*/
    ob_start();

    SOME PHP OR HTML CODE HERE

    /*we are finished, we want to store the rest*/
    $storecodeincache .= ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    /*not neccessary, just when you call the script you see what has been cached*/
    echo $storecodeincache ;

    /*write all cached content into the file*/
    $handle = fopen('safe://pathwhereyousavethecachedcontent', 'w'); 

    fwrite($handle, $storecodeincache ); 

    fclose($handle); 

    ?>
```

The most important part is that `$storecodeincache .= ob_get_contents();` at the beggining when we stopped caching - this stores a **non-executed** PHP code into the cached file - note that at this point we are "not caching" but we will store this code into the cached file anywa! Because we did

```
$storecodeincache .= ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

which ended caching. And we are doing

```
ob_start();
```

afterwards (which starts caching again). But between, the PHP cache is off. You can turn off PHP caching at any point like this, store any **non-executed** PHP code into the same variable used for caching "already executed code" and then move on (turn on cache again and continue).

Comment: Sorry, but were will I have to put this Code?
Around the PHP include? 
( include("themes/header.html");)

Comment: Use this code in your "caching script" - this code lets you create a cached file which you will include afterwards. This caching script should be called again and again to get a new version of file every few minutes (use server CRON for this). If you just need regular caching in your script you use `ob_start();` at the beggining of the file, then you store the content into the variable using `ob_get_contents();`, then you clean buffer `ob_end_clean();` and then you save the result into some other php file using `fwrite` - that file will be like `result.php` which you include anywhere you want.

Comment: Thank you
but I found an other way so that I don't have to cash php :)